Imposter - xPath not valid for capture?
The docs have this example:
- path: "/users"
  method: POST
  capture:
    petName:
      xPath: "/env:Envelope/env:Body/pets:animal/pets:name"
      store: testStore
      xmlNamespaces:
        env: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        pets: "urn:com:example:petstore"

But I'm getting an error
14:01:37 INFO i.g.i.Imposter - Starting mock engine 4.0.0
14:01:37 DEBUG i.g.i.c.u.ConfigUtil - Loading configuration file: .\configs\gm-dds-config.yaml
14:01:38 DEBUG i.g.i.c.u.ConfigUtil - Loading configuration file: .\configs\single-response-config.yaml
14:01:38 DEBUG i.g.i.p.PluginManager - Loaded 5 plugin(s): [js-detector, store-detector, rest, js-graal, store-inmem]
14:01:39 ERROR i.v.c.i.l.c.VertxIsolatedDeployer - Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring plugin: rest
at io.gatehill.imposter.plugin.PluginManagerImpl.configurePlugins(PluginManagerImpl.kt:133) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at io.gatehill.imposter.plugin.PluginManagerImpl.startPlugins(PluginManagerImpl.kt:91) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at io.gatehill.imposter.Imposter$start$1.invokeSuspend(Imposter.kt:132) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697) ~[imposter.jar:?]
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684) ~[imposter.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading configuration file: my-config.yml , reason: Unrecognized field "xPath" (class io.gatehill.imposter.plugin.config.capture.ItemCaptureConfig), not marked as ignorable (12 known properties: "requestBody", "const", "queryParam", "pathParam", "formParam", "phase", "requestHeader", "jsonPath", "key", "store", "expression", "enabled"])

with the following config
---
plugin: rest 
basePath: "/dds"
system:
  xmlNamespaces:
    soap: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    star: "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"

resources:
  - path: "/appointments"
    method: POST
    capture:
      serviceappointmentId:
        xPath: "/star:ProcessServiceAppointment/star:ProcessServiceAppointmentDataArea/star:ServiceAppointment/star:ServiceAppointmentHeader/star:SecondaryDealerNumberID"
        store: requestData
        xmlNamespaces:
          star: "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"
    requestBody:
      xPath: "/star:ProcessServiceAppointment/star:ProcessServiceAppointmentDataArea"
      operator: Exists
    response:
      statusCode: 202
      content: "appt received"

Actually what I'm trying to do is capture the whole payload, but I switched it to just a single data item to as shown in the docs to see if that would work.
Note that if I leave out the capture settings, then the xPath matching works fine.

This was an error in the documentation (since fixed). The xPath (and associated xmlNamespaces config) should’ve been shown as nested below the requestBody element in the capture block.
Here’s an updated example:
- path: "/users"
  method: POST
  capture:
    petName:
      store: testStore
      requestBody:
        xPath: "/env:Envelope/env:Body/pets:animal/pets:name"
        xmlNamespaces:
          env: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          pets: "urn:com:example:petstore"

For your config, the relevant capture portion would be:
    capture:
      serviceappointmentId:
        store: requestData
        requestBody:
          xPath: "/star:ProcessServiceAppointment/star:ProcessServiceAppointmentDataArea/star:ServiceAppointment/star:ServiceAppointmentHeader/star:SecondaryDealerNumberID"
          xmlNamespaces:
            star: "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"


Full disclosure: project maintainer here - thank you to the author of this question for filing a bug.

